# How to get ion-checkbox multiple select value in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-checkbox

```
    <div *ngIf="testList.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let member of testList">
    <ion-label>{{member?.testName || 'N/A'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" [(ngModel)]="member.checked"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>

[{testID: 1, testName: " test1", testAmount: "500", testDescription: ""},
{testID: 2, testName: " test2", testAmount: "500", testDescription: ""},
{testID: 3, testName: "dgdfgd", testAmount: "150", testDescription: ""},
{testID: 4, testName: "UricAcid", testAmount: "200", testDescription: ""}]

<button (click)="gettstdata()">Done</button>
```

How to get all checkbox value like multi select when click on Done button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="testList.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let member of testList">
    <ion-label>{{member?.testName || 'N/A'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" (click)="selectMember(member)" [(ngModel)]="member.checked"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>
<button ion-button (click)="checkAll()">Done</button>
```

in ts:

```
  testList: any = [
       {testID: 1, testName: " test1", checked: false},
       {testID: 2, testName: " test2", checked: false},
       {testID: 3, testName: "dgdfgd", checked: false},
       {testID: 4, testName: "UricAcid", checked: false}
    ]

selectedArray :any = [];

checkAll(){
  for(let i =0; i <= this.testList.length; i++) {
    this.testList[i].checked = true;
  }
 console.log(this.testList);
}

selectMember(data){
 if (data.checked == true) {
    this.selectedArray.push(data);
  } else {
   let newArray = this.selectedArray.filter(function(el) {
     return el.testID !== data.testID;
  });
   this.selectedArray = newArray;
 }
 console.log(this.selectedArray);
}
```

Comment: But checkAll() not working, but i'm using like this after selectMember(data)                   
` checkAll(){
 console.log(this.selectedArray);
} `

Comment: remove is not working. i mean if it checked , add to array. but if i unchecked some options, its not removing from array. can you help me ?

Answer (score 6):

There's several way to achieve this.

-You can use (change), I wrote you some extra methods you will need for common things when you work with checkboxes

```
 <div *ngIf="testList.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let member of testList">
    <ion-label>{{member?.testName || 'N/A'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" (change)="addCheckbox($event,member.testName)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>

<button (click)='getCheckedBoxes()'>Done</button>
```

In your .ts file

```
checked = [];
//Adds the checkedbox to the array and check if you unchecked it
addCheckbox(event, checkbox : String) { 
    if ( event.target.checked ) {
      this.checked.push(checkbox);
    } else {
      let index = this.removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox);
      this.checked.splice(index,1);
    }
  }

  //Removes checkbox from array when you uncheck it
  removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox : String) {
    return this.checked.findIndex((category)=>{
      return category === checkbox;
    })
  }

  //Empties array with checkedboxes
  emptyCheckedArray() {
    this.checked = [];
  }

 getCheckedBoxes() {
   //Do whatever
   console.log(this.checked);
 }
```

Comment: getting empty like this []

Comment: Use (ionChange) instead of (change) event.

Answer (score 5):

@Patricio Vargas's Answer is working but you need to use `(ionChange)` instead of `(change)`

Also change the if statement condition from `(event.target.checked)` to `(event.checked)`

```
<div *ngIf="testList.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let member of testList">
    <ion-label>{{member?.testName || 'N/A'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark" (ionChange)="addCheckbox($event,member.testName)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>

<button (click)='getCheckedBoxes()'>Done</button>
```

In your .ts file

```
checked = [];
//Adds the checkedbox to the array and check if you unchecked it
addCheckbox(event, checkbox : String) { 
    if ( event.checked ) {
      this.checked.push(checkbox);
    } else {
      let index = this.removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox);
      this.checked.splice(index,1);
    }
  }

  //Removes checkbox from array when you uncheck it
  removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox : String) {
    return this.checked.findIndex((category)=>{
      return category === checkbox;
    })
  }

  //Empties array with checkedboxes
  emptyCheckedArray() {
    this.checked = [];
  }

 getCheckedBoxes() {
   //Do whatever
   console.log(this.checked);
 }
```